# CloudFormation template: reduce boilerplate code

Tags: aws-cloudformation, boilerplate

I'm trying to compose CF template to deploy a serverless system consisting of several Lambdas. In my case, Lambda resource descriptions share a lot of properties; the only difference is filename and handler function.

How can I define something like common set of parameters in my template?

This boilerplate is awful:

```
  LambdaCreateUser:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: BucketForLambdas
        S3Key: create_user.zip
      Handler: create_user.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Role: 
        Fn::GetAtt: [ LambdaRole , "Arn" ]
      Environment:
        Variables: { "EnvTable": !Ref EnvironmentTable, "UsersTable": !Ref UsersTable }
  LambdaDeleteUser:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: BucketForLambdas
        S3Key: delete_user.zip 
      Handler: delete_user.lambda_handler  
      Runtime: python3.7   
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ LambdaRole , "Arn" ]
      Environment:
        Variables: { "EnvTable": !Ref EnvironmentTable, "UsersTable": !Ref UsersTable }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/) which is a layer of syntactic sugar on top on CloudFormation. A basic representation of your template with AWS SAM would look like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: python3.7
    Environment:
      Variables:
        EnvTable: !Ref EnvironmentTable
        UsersTable: !Ref UsersTable

Resources:
  LambdaCreateUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: BucketForLambdas
        S3Key: create_user.zip
      Handler: create_user.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
  LambdaDeleteUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: BucketForLambdas
        S3Key: delete_user.zip 
      Handler: delete_user.lambda_handler  
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
```

But that's not the end. You can replace the code definition with a path to your code or even inline code and use `sam build` and `sam package` to build and upload your artifacts. You can also probably replace the role definition with [SAM policy templates](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/policy_templates.rst) for further reduction of boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks @Dunedan, will definitely take a look on it.

My CF template also deploys a couple of DynamoDB databases, S3 bucket, IAM role for Lambdas and inline initialization Lambda for databases, hope it's all possible with SAM (if it is just a syntactic sugar for CF).

Comment: Ideally, the code would look like this. Like, DefaultProperties are defined somewhere else; and property listed in function definition is overriding defaults.

`LambdaCreateUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties: !Ref DefaultProperties
    S3Key: create_user.zip
    Handler: create_user.lambda_handler
LambdaDeleteUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties: !Ref DefaultProperties
    S3Key: delete_user.zip
    Handler: delete_user.lambda_handler`